# remove the element which has great difference from others in a list

Tags: python, list, filtering

Python for help
I have a list including following elements

```
[[**287.5** 235.5  24.3]
  [**287.5** 297.5  24.3]
  [**287.5** 359.5  24.3]
  [ 56.5 151.5  25.4]]
```

I want to remove [ 56.5 151.5  25.4], this one since 56.5 has a huge difference from others (287.5). I want to return to

```
[[287.5 235.5  24.3]
  [287.5 297.5  24.3]
  [287.5 359.5  24.3]]
```

I have thought for hours, but without come up with a good idea, any one can help?

Comment: how do you define huge? some threshold value may be?

Comment: You criteria need to be clarified. You should also post valid Python literals, so people willing to help can just c'n'p your code.

Comment: Perhaps you want to remove the row that causes the greatest standard deviation in each column?

Comment: @HengShao Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please see the post below - a response inferred by your examples.  I encourage you to revise your question.  Makes sure examples run in Python.  Finally, be clear about what you want in writing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it is unclear what is requested.  You may be asking *"How do I choose a combination of three lists that minimizes the [variances](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Variance.html) for each column?"*

Here is a way in Python 3:

**Given**

```
import itertools as it
import statistics as stats


a = [[287.5, 235.5,  24.3],
     [287.5, 297.5,  24.3],
     [287.5, 359.5,  24.3],
     [ 56.5, 151.5,  25.4]]
```

**Code**

```
def sum_of_variances(combs):
    """Return the sum of variances for the columns in each combination."""
    cols_per_combs = [list(zip(*x)) for x in combs]
    return [sum([stats.variance(col) for col in cols]) for cols in cols_per_combs]


def optimal_combination(lst):
    """Return the combination that minimizes the columnar variances."""
    combs = [x for x in it.combinations(lst, 3)]
    summed_vars = sum_of_variances(combs)
    idx = min(enumerate(summed_vars), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
    return combs[idx]


optimal_combination(a)
# ([287.5, 235.5, 24.3], [287.5, 297.5, 24.3], [287.5, 359.5, 24.3])
```

---

**Details**

Find all combinations of *three* lists:

```
>>> combs = [x for x in it.combinations(a, 3)]
>>> combs
[([287.5, 235.5, 24.3], [287.5, 297.5, 24.3], [287.5, 359.5, 24.3]),
 ([287.5, 235.5, 24.3], [287.5, 297.5, 24.3], [56.5, 151.5, 25.4]),
 ([287.5, 235.5, 24.3], [287.5, 359.5, 24.3], [56.5, 151.5, 25.4]),
 ([287.5, 297.5, 24.3], [287.5, 359.5, 24.3], [56.5, 151.5, 25.4])]
```

Look along the columns for all combinations by zipping:

```
>>> cols_per_combs = [list(zip(*x)) for x in combs]
>>> cols_per_combs
[[(287.5, 287.5, 287.5), (235.5, 297.5, 359.5), (24.3, 24.3, 24.3)],
 [(287.5, 287.5, 56.5), (235.5, 297.5, 151.5), (24.3, 24.3, 25.4)],
 [(287.5, 287.5, 56.5), (235.5, 359.5, 151.5), (24.3, 24.3, 25.4)],
 [(287.5, 287.5, 56.5), (297.5, 359.5, 151.5), (24.3, 24.3, 25.4)]]
```

We compute the variance of the columns to give a measure of how different the values are in each column.  Notice, the first option (index `0`) shows  columns with the smallest differences:

```
>>> variance_per_cols = [[stats.variance(col) for col in cols] for cols in cols_per_combs]
>>> variance_per_cols
[[0.0, 3844.0, 0.0],
 [17787.0, 5369.333333333333, 0.4033333333333317],
 [17787.0, 10949.333333333334, 0.4033333333333317],
 [17787.0, 11404.0, 0.4033333333333317]]
```

If we sum these variances, we can still see which combination minimizes these differences, i.e. index `0`:

```
>>> summed_vars = sum_of_variances(combs)
>>> summed_vars
[3844.0, 23156.736666666664, 28736.736666666668, 29191.403333333332]
```

`optimal_combination()` returns the combination that minimizes the summed variances, i.e. index `combs[0]`.